# Android - Source code for phonegap cordova.jar

Tags: java, android, cordova

I am working on PhoneGap for android and it use cordova-1.5.0.jar, I want to see source code of that jar, tried but i didn't found any source code for that jar.
Anyone provide link for that source code
Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

http://cordova.apache.org/

you can find the link to the git repositories for each supported OSes there,

Github link for android git:
https://github.com/apache/cordova-android

Comment: Just wanted to add that for anyone who wants to clone the git repo for the android source, use this url: https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/incubator-cordova-android.git

Comment: These URLs have changed. Android git: https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=cordova-android.git;a=summary